# SQL Server : how to add the date and time of record register acording to client time zone

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm having a problem with adding a date and time when a record added into my database. The problem is because I have clients from different time zones. What I thought of doing is I'm allowing the users to change the time zone and I save it in a table `tbl_timezone` which keeps `UserIDReg` (for example 1) and `timezone_time` (for example +2)

What I was thinking is while I try to add the records into the database to search for that user in `tbl_timezone` and add the `timezone_time` into the system current time which is always `UTC+00:00`.

Appreciate helping me solve this problem.

Here is the stored procedure for adding the record

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[Cp_Recivers_Insert]
     @SmsR_SmsID  bigint  ,
     @SmsR_UserIDReg  int  
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION SmsR
        IF @SmsR_DateReg IS NULL
        BEGIN 
            SET @SmsR_DateReg = (SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS datetime)) 
        END

        INSERT INTO Prj_SmsRecivers (SmsR_SmsID, SmsR_DateReg, SmsR_UserIDReg)
        VALUES (@SmsR_SmsID, @SmsR_DateReg, @SmsR_UserIDReg)

        SELECT @@IDENTITY As SmsR_ID
        COMMIT TRANSACTION SmsR
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION SmsR
    END CATCH
END
```

Comment: I would recommend to use **`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`** instead of anything else (like `@@IDENTITY`) to grab the newly inserted identity value. [See this blog post for an explanation as to WHY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

Comment: I would advice you to look into `datetimeoffset ` to help with handling international datetimes.

Comment: Thanks for the advice i have a variable 'declare @zone as varchar(20)' how can i add this variable instead of +02:00 in below query  SELECT SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() GetCurrentOffSet;
SELECT SWITCHOFFSET(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), '+02:00') ;'